# Cannot override class properties inside use Tag

Tags: css, svg

I need to change `SVG` `fill` property by adding up a class. Say from `#fff` to `#000`. I tried fiddling with two different methods. I got successful with one of either method. Rather I don't prefer the method to use which I was successful.

**Method 1:** - Succesful.

I just added a class on the body tag and over-ride the `svg fill` property. Take a look at the code below

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
var body = document.body
var count = false;
button.onclick = changeBackground;

function changeBackground() {
  body.classList.toggle('toggle');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #3d3d3d;
}

.sheetListWhite {
  fill: #fff;
}

.slBGColor {
  fill: #3d3d3d;
}

.toggle {
  background: #fff;
}

.toggle .sheetListWhite {
  fill: #3d3d3d;
}

.toggle .slBGColor {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg width="18px" height="18px" viewBox="-2 -2 13 13"> 
    <use xlink:href="#sharedByMe" class="sheetListWhite"></use>
</svg>

<button id="btn"> Change background</button>

<svg style="display:none;">
  <symbol id="sharedByMe">
    <g id="user-(5)">
      <path d="M5.76735992,5.07170748 C6.58617985,4.59194553 7.12018634,3.73525063 7.12018634,2.74147173 C7.12020298,1.23365988 5.8385508,0 4.27211846,0 C2.70568612,0 1.42403394,1.23365988 1.42403394,2.74147173 C1.42403394,3.73525063 1.95804042,4.59196155 2.77686035,5.07170748 C1.35282642,5.58574044 0.284796801,6.78512932 0,8.22439918 L0.712025292,8.22439918 C1.06802962,6.64806134 2.52768396,5.48292744 4.27211846,5.48292744 C6.01655296,5.48292744 7.47620731,6.64804532 7.83221163,8.22439918 L8.54423692,8.22439918 C8.25944012,6.75085832 7.19141051,5.55146944 5.76735992,5.07170748 Z M2.13605923,2.74147173 C2.13605923,1.61062486 3.09729421,0.685371939 4.27211846,0.685371939 C5.44694272,0.685371939 6.40817769,1.61062486 6.40817769,2.74147173 C6.40817769,3.87231861 5.44694272,4.79757153 4.27211846,4.79757153 C3.09729421,4.79757153 2.13605923,3.87231861 2.13605923,2.74147173 Z" id="Shape"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="shared-folder" transform="translate(6.111111, 5.294118)">
      <ellipse id="Oval-6" class="slBGColor" cx="2.44444444" cy="2.35294118" rx="2.44444444" ry="2.35294118"></ellipse>
      <path d="M3.54444101,1.45883032 C3.94870693,1.45883032 4.27777778,1.13170727 4.27777778,0.729415161 C4.27777778,0.327123049 3.94870693,0 3.54444101,0 C3.14017508,0 2.81110424,0.327140144 2.81110424,0.729415161 C2.81110424,0.781778783 2.81720578,0.832655093 2.82779325,0.881924423 L1.89436023,1.34613656 C1.7598169,1.19301186 1.56441282,1.09413129 1.34443069,1.09413129 C0.940181958,1.09411419 0.611111111,1.42125434 0.611111111,1.82352936 C0.611111111,2.22580437 0.940181958,2.55294452 1.34444788,2.55294452 C1.56439563,2.55294452 1.75974815,2.45413233 1.89429148,2.30105891 L2.82781043,2.76516848 C2.81720578,2.81442071 2.81110424,2.86527993 2.81110424,2.91764355 C2.81110424,3.31991857 3.14017508,3.64705871 3.54444101,3.64705871 C3.94870693,3.64705871 4.27777778,3.31993566 4.27777778,2.91764355 C4.27777778,2.51536853 3.94870693,2.18822839 3.54444101,2.18822839 C3.32445888,2.18822839 3.12903762,2.28710896 2.99449429,2.44025076 L2.06104408,1.97615829 C2.07164873,1.92685476 2.07778465,1.87594426 2.07778465,1.82352936 C2.07778465,1.77116573 2.07168311,1.72028942 2.06109564,1.67102009 L2.99452866,1.20680796 C3.12905481,1.35994975 3.32444169,1.45883032 3.54444101,1.45883032 Z" id="Shape"></path>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

See the fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/nuorcj0a/2/)

**Method 2** - Failed

Instead of adding the class directly to the body tag i added it on a div.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
var body = document.getElementById("check");
var count = false;
button.onclick = changeBackground;

function changeBackground() {
  body.classList.toggle('toggle');
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3d3d3d
}

.sheetListWhite {
  fill: #fff;
}

.slBGColor {
  fill: #3d3d3d;
}

.toggle {
  background: #fff;
}

.toggle .sheetListWhite {
  background: #3d3d3d
}

.toggle .slBGColor {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="check">
  <svg width="18px" height="18px" viewBox="-2 -2 13 13"> 
    <use xlink:href="#sharedByMe" class="sheetListWhite"></use>
  </svg>
  <button id="btn"> Change background</button>
</div>

<svg style="display:none;">
  <symbol id="sharedByMe">
    <g id="user-(5)">
      <path d="M5.76735992,5.07170748 C6.58617985,4.59194553 7.12018634,3.73525063 7.12018634,2.74147173 C7.12020298,1.23365988 5.8385508,0 4.27211846,0 C2.70568612,0 1.42403394,1.23365988 1.42403394,2.74147173 C1.42403394,3.73525063 1.95804042,4.59196155 2.77686035,5.07170748 C1.35282642,5.58574044 0.284796801,6.78512932 0,8.22439918 L0.712025292,8.22439918 C1.06802962,6.64806134 2.52768396,5.48292744 4.27211846,5.48292744 C6.01655296,5.48292744 7.47620731,6.64804532 7.83221163,8.22439918 L8.54423692,8.22439918 C8.25944012,6.75085832 7.19141051,5.55146944 5.76735992,5.07170748 Z M2.13605923,2.74147173 C2.13605923,1.61062486 3.09729421,0.685371939 4.27211846,0.685371939 C5.44694272,0.685371939 6.40817769,1.61062486 6.40817769,2.74147173 C6.40817769,3.87231861 5.44694272,4.79757153 4.27211846,4.79757153 C3.09729421,4.79757153 2.13605923,3.87231861 2.13605923,2.74147173 Z" id="Shape"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="shared-folder" transform="translate(6.111111, 5.294118)">
      <ellipse id="Oval-6" class="slBGColor" cx="2.44444444" cy="2.35294118" rx="2.44444444" ry="2.35294118"></ellipse>
      <path d="M3.54444101,1.45883032 C3.94870693,1.45883032 4.27777778,1.13170727 4.27777778,0.729415161 C4.27777778,0.327123049 3.94870693,0 3.54444101,0 C3.14017508,0 2.81110424,0.327140144 2.81110424,0.729415161 C2.81110424,0.781778783 2.81720578,0.832655093 2.82779325,0.881924423 L1.89436023,1.34613656 C1.7598169,1.19301186 1.56441282,1.09413129 1.34443069,1.09413129 C0.940181958,1.09411419 0.611111111,1.42125434 0.611111111,1.82352936 C0.611111111,2.22580437 0.940181958,2.55294452 1.34444788,2.55294452 C1.56439563,2.55294452 1.75974815,2.45413233 1.89429148,2.30105891 L2.82781043,2.76516848 C2.81720578,2.81442071 2.81110424,2.86527993 2.81110424,2.91764355 C2.81110424,3.31991857 3.14017508,3.64705871 3.54444101,3.64705871 C3.94870693,3.64705871 4.27777778,3.31993566 4.27777778,2.91764355 C4.27777778,2.51536853 3.94870693,2.18822839 3.54444101,2.18822839 C3.32445888,2.18822839 3.12903762,2.28710896 2.99449429,2.44025076 L2.06104408,1.97615829 C2.07164873,1.92685476 2.07778465,1.87594426 2.07778465,1.82352936 C2.07778465,1.77116573 2.07168311,1.72028942 2.06109564,1.67102009 L2.99452866,1.20680796 C3.12905481,1.35994975 3.32444169,1.45883032 3.54444101,1.45883032 Z" id="Shape"></path>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Fiddle it [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/nuorcj0a/1/)

Now you can see I can't override the following classes **.slBGColor, .sheetListWhite**

How can I get rid of this bug? Any Idea. I don't want to use the svg tag directly instead of `use tag`. I mean I would like to use all of my SVG from an external resource. Any Help

Thanks.

Comment: Not so sure why `.toggle .sheetListWhite {
  background: #3d3d3d
}` was commented out in the fiddle, but what exactly isn't working? Both SVG's update their fills when I toggle, so maybe I understood you wrong?

Comment: I suspect <use> is not appropriate to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The "insides" of a `<use>` cannot be addressed via the `<use>` element. It is considered opaque/private.  As far as the browser is concerned, there is no `class="slBGColor"` inside the `<div>`. So `.toggle .slBGColor {}` does nothing.

You *can* make it work by restyling the symbol definition itself.

For example, if I make the following two changes to your example, the ellipse in the symbol changes colour based on whether the "toggle" class is set or not.

```
var body = document.body;

.toggle div {
  background: red;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nuorcj0a/4/

However, be aware that will also change any other references to that symbol on the page.

Comment: Change ur working fiddle .toggle div {
  background: white;

}

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly? That is not a helpful statement. What doesn't my fiddle do that you need it to do?

Comment: Obviously if you change the div background to white, you'll also need to change the SVG ellipse to white also. .`toggle .slBGColor{ fill: white; }`

Comment: Sorry @paul. I cant understand what's is symbol definition.

Comment: Have you changed body element reference. Is that you mean by symbol definition

Comment: The symbol definition is the part inside the `<symbol>` tags.  You can style the symbol based on its actuial position in the DOM. But you cannot style it based on which `<use>` references it.

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully make it clearer what I changed, and why.